# How can I browse source code on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have a lot of downtime on the subway each morning and evening, and I'd like to be able to review source code for various projects I'm working on.

Are there any apps that can help with this?  I'd like something that lets me browse a hierarchical tree of source files and that does syntax highlighting.

Comment: IMHO AFAIK hardly:) Try listening to podcasts and MP3s from InfoQ...

Comment: @Gabriel- doesn't help if you are deaf/hard of hearing & have difficulty understanding recorded voices.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for an app... Do you know objective-c? :)

Comment: I think the iPhone display is too small for effective reading of the source code. maybe an iPad? maybe a tablet pc?

Comment: ah.. sorry, I am myself visually impaired... with code revies you might have some difficulties with navigation, you would have to parse the code... I would still go for article reading than code review on small screen.

Comment: The iPhone display is too small for effective reading of the source code???  But it can read news and books?

Answer (score 1):

Leave your desktop machine online and use [LogMeIn Ignition for iPhone/iPod Touch](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/ignition/iphone/)